# How to use model.predict() to reproduce model.evaluate() output in Keras

Tags: python, keras

I have a Keras model with the final row as:

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='adam')
```

After the training process, I want to load evaluate the model in another code. I am generating a prediction and ground truth using:

```
y_predict = model.predict_generator(generator = testing_generator, steps=steps,verbose=0)
y_true = np.asarray(feature_extractor.classes, dtype='float32')
print('predicted {} samples with {} classes'.format(y_predict.shape[0],y_predict.shape[1]))            
        #Calculate score and error
acc = keras.metrics.binary_accuracy(y_true, y_predict)
err = keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(tf.convert_to_tensor(y_true, np.float32), tf.convert_to_tensor(y_predict, np.float32))
sess = tf.InteractiveSession() 
acc_now = np.mean(acc.eval())
err_now = np.mean(err.eval())
sess.close()
print('Acc and Err from model.predict: {},{}'.format(acc_now,err_now))
print('Model.evaluate output: {}'.format(model.evaluate_generator(generator = testing_generator, steps=steps,verbose=0)))
```

And then I wish to evaluate accuracy, error rate and confusion matrix. The reason I am using `predict` instead of `evaluate` is so that I will be able to produce the confusion matrix. otherwise, I will have to use both which is computationally expensive.

The problem is, I am getting different values:

> Acc and Err from model.predict: 0.8237550854682922,12.75771713256836
>
> Model.evaluate output: [13.05123828162994, 0.10646823157343649]

The accuracy dropped from 0.82 in my method to 0.1 in the model evaluate output. Am I converting the `model.predict()` output as required? How do I make a Model evaluation with the results of `model.predict()`?

I have also followed [this github issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5140) and tried the solution of setting `m=Model(x,x)`. I have the same shape and type for `y_predict` and `y_true`. and still this method yields:

> Scores from m.evaluate: [12.757719990861846, 0.11333714980412431]

With the example code:

```
        x = Input(y_predict.shape[1:])
        m = Model(x, x)
        m.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='adam')
        scores = m.evaluate(y_predict, y_true, batch_size=256, verbose=0) 
        print('Scores from m.evaluate: {}'.format(scores))
```

Here, the accuracy is low, though still different from the `evaluate()` output and the error it the same as the `predict()` part.

---

Adding model definition:

```
num_rows = data_in[-2]
num_columns = data_in[-1]
num_channels = data_in[-3]
num_labels = data_out[-1]


# Construct model     
model = Sequential()
for i in range(cnn_size):
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=2**(i)*16, kernel_size=kernel_size, input_shape=(num_channels, num_rows, num_columns), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=pool_size))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(Dense(num_labels, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='adam')
```

Where `data_in = (1, 40, 180)` and `data_out = (1, 10)`

B.T.W I am aware I can implement my own numpy solution for these statistics but I want to use the same function as Keras to avoid implementation variations.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a look at this article. It is written in German, but all the Comments in the Code and the instructions coming with it are in English, so it shouldn't be a problem. He has a kinda similar approach with clear instructions. Just scroll down to the section "Fehleranalyse".

https://www.mt-ag.com/so-entwirft-man-ein-top-cnn/

Comment: He does exactly what I am trying to avoid which is executing `model.evaluate()` once and `model.predict()` once.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a classic classification problem with `'softmax'` and `'categorical_crossentropy'`, you probably need to calculate a categorical accuracy, not a binary accuracy.

For the case `y_true` is one-hot encoded (this seems to be your case, since you're using `'categorical_crossentropy'`):

```
keras.metrics.categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred)
```

For the case `y_true` is numeric labels (integers):

```
keras.metrics.sparse_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred)
```

You can also calculate the accuracy on your own with:

```
trueLabels = np.argmax(y_true_numpy, axis=-1) #this line only if y_true is one-hot
predLabels = np.argmax(y_pred_numpy, axis=-1)    
acc = np.mean(trueLabels == predLabels)
```

---

About the loss, I think you are looking the results backwards. Evaluate loss should be `13.05...`. Your calculated loss is close to it: `12.75...`.

Now, if two different methods that seem correct are yielding the same result, I suspect that the greater result given by `evaluate` may be coming from an additional loss in your model. Keras evaluation sums up all losses in the model, including weight regularizations, maybe loss weights, manually added losses, etc.

We would need to see your entire model to detect why there is a difference here.

---

About the loss with the model definition given:

It doesn't seem to have anything that would affect the loss, and the result should be correct indeed.

In this case, there are two other things that might be causing the difference:

- The `testing_generator` and the `feature_extractor` may not be working exactly the same

  - Besides a possible bug, there is the possibility that you are iterating the same generator twice, and if the generator is a `yield` type, Keras queue may have made it not start at the same point at the second time you use the generator
- A very remote possibility that your Keras version is buggy (or some configuration that is not in the code here is changed) and the Dropouts are taking effect during evaluation.

  - A quick check is to perform `evaluate` more than once to see if the results are exactly the same

Comment: Assuming I have used 'm.evaluate()` method with the same compile line, that is, the same metrics and loss,  why is that I am not getting the same metric being it `categorical_accuracy` or `binary_accuracy`?

Comment: Keras automatically selects a different accuracy depending on your model and data. If you want a specific accuracy, you must say it explicitly. It probably depends on more than just the chosen loss, the final activation might participate.

Comment: Compile the models with `'categorical_accuracy'`.

Comment: I have added the definition for the model.

Comment: Updated the answer. I can't think of anything else for the loss difference.